# Random enclosing path with dots on path

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I would like to generate a SVG/canvas using JavaScript that contains an enclosing path (a line that starts and ends at the same place) with random number of points that should be equidistant from each other (on the path, not in terms of space).

What library can be used to achieve this effect and if possible, can an example be provided?

Angela

Comment: Are you talking about a regular polygon ( versus an irregular one)? Either way, could you possibly provide a sketchy paint drawing or something to illustrate what you're after. I would use [`d3.js`](http://d3js.org) for this task.

Comment: You don't say whether the shape has to be a simple polygon or if it is allowed to be self-intersecting.

Comment: @Luxelin I'm looking for an irregular path, like one drawn by hand. something like this http://www.ducati.ms/forums/attachments/road-racing/75447d1283356290-austin-f1-track-done-deal-they-have-drawing-f1-austin-track.jpg  except, of course, I don't need any of the visual effects here, just the line

Comment: @BigBadaboom I don't think I'm looking for a polygon, more of a irregular path that is generated by JavaScript

Comment: @Angela But it's almost a regular polygon if all the points need to be a certain distance from the two connecting points (it only isn't regular b/c, as your picture demonstrates, you want your shape to possibly be concave, not just convex).

Comment: @Luxelin yeah, that's what I mean. Where can I find a D3 example for this?

Answer (score 0):

For SVG you can use the Snap library and in particular use the getPointAtLength method to get equidistant points along a path.

http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.getPointAtLength

In html Canvas a path can be any combination of line segments and curves (quadratic & cubic Bezier curves).  Therefore to plot equidistant points on a path you must mathematically interpolate along each line segment and curve using the appropriate formulae.

For line segments this usually involves calculating the length of the line segment and then "lerping" (Google!) using your specified distance.

For curves this usually involves using the equations for the curve and plotting numerous points along that line.  Then connect those points with line segments and again "lerping" along those segments at your specified distance.

Comment: @Angela: Here's a demo using Raphael (an ancestor of snapsvg) and .getPointAtLength:  http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html